# Single rotation DC motor using 3 bit binary counter

Tags: dc-motor, logic-gates, binary

My system activates when a thrown switch turns on a DC motor with an 8 hole optical wheel on its shaft. A photo emitter / detector is used to generate pulses sent to three negative edge T flip flops in order to generate 3 bit binary counter (B2, B1, B0). The switch signal and B2 are run through an OR gate and then an additional T Flip Flop. The initial up-down of the switch toggles the flip flop and turns on the motor. When B2 goes from 1 to 0 after 8 pulses it activates the toggle again and the motor turns off. The switch can then be thrown to repeat the process.

In my setup however my photocoupler will not generate a binary count at all. I have tests the binary counter with a switch and it works. I included a hard reset button to ensure all my Q's in my flip flops start low.

Please give advice on sources of error! Thank you.

EDIT: I ended up using 3 10uF capacitors across the top rails and then a 100nF between the battery terminals. It reduced the noise from the motor and the 1 rotation cycle was achieved. At times I still was getting a little noise so I used a seperate 9V battery to power my motor and everything worked perfectly. Thank you for the input.

[image: Schematic]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not an answer, use a **comment** next time.

Comment: Also, you **edited out** your question, that is not how this site works. Please learn how to use it properly! Now this question is useless as there is no question.

Comment: Uhh... This is a question, and you want to shut it down because its "not an answer". I'm a little confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It rather looks like your "photo-detector" circuit does not have the oomph to over-ride that 200R pull-up to a decent enough logic level to clock the flip-flop, especially not with that extra diode in series.

Since you used such a low value pull-down I assume you are using TTL. As such, you would be better to use the device to pull low on a much larger resistor. (If you are using CMOS, just up the resistor value).

You have not indicated what the sensor type is so I will guess a photo-diode.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fa1QIV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

However, the other issue you will have with this set-up is it will be VERY sensitive to ambient light. The detector may get swamped or triggered by other sources. Here is where you are in catch 22. You want a smaller resistance to be less sensitive, but one high enough for it to work over the entire tolerance range of the parts and mechanical alignment.

So unless the thing is completely covered, a better method uses a modulated LED signal, a receiver that does not saturate, and a detector circuit or algorithm.

Comment: Okay I added two 2K resistors in series to the photo diode emitter/detector and it works fine, I can count through the entire binary process when using a notecard to block the transmission. However now when I hook up my motor, exactly as shown, it makes the binary counter LEDs flicker or go on. I have no idea how the motor could be sending a signal to all the binary counters.

Comment: @NLhere that is a different problem. The issues you are now seeing is because when transitioning an encoder goes through a gray area when the logic signal is neither on nor off. As such your counter will count away at whatever rate the noise in the system dictates. You really need two sensors to give you a quadrature signal. Either that or a comparator with lots of hysteresis. It's sort of like bouncing on a switch, but worse.

Comment: @NLhere You may want to post a new question for that issue.

Comment: thank you for the quick replies. Will post a new question!

Answer (score 0):

On your photo receiver, reverse the power connections, connect the resistor to +5 and the optical receiver to ground. Because a 220 ohm resistor resistor to ground is an unreliable logical "0". Also replace it with a higher value, try 5K to 10K. The photo detector will pulse the input signal low.  Also photo sensors generally must be reversed biased (connected "backward") to operate correctly, so try changing the direction of your photo sensor.